# Strange behaviour if wanting to edit after an edited question or answer

Tags: bug, editor

I have noticed strange (editor) behaviour lately when a question or answer has been edited.

They do reload/refresh by themselves, yet if I remain on the page without refreshing it and click on the "edit" option myself for those, it won't go into the editor, but seems to want to reload in what seems to be some type of an iframe.

It will only work (the editor loads) if I reload the page.

The only way to actually test this for someone here, would (probably) be to actually monitor a question and/or answer(s) that will be edited.

For example: This answer today https://stackoverflow.com/a/39227631/ originally had a syntax error and they fixed it. But when I wanted to fix something else, the editor did not show. It reloaded the answer instead.

Has anyone else noticed this type of behaviour?

This has been going on for a while actually (a week or so) and thought it was temporary problem.

The browser I am using is Firefox 48.0.2

Note: I do not have any other web browser installed to keep testing this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you. I'm wondering if I should delete my question then or just mark it as one.

Comment: The more questions are staying as dupe of that bug, the higher pressure gets on the devs to fix it asap.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Good point.