# Vote to close popup disappeared when an edit to the question was made during voting

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

I posted [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333473/1415724) not long ago about an editing bug that I might add, has since been resolved.

Yet I noticed something else this evening (just a few minutes before my posting this question) in the following question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322674/open-source-gift-card-loyalty-system-like-ackroo

Where the OP had originally posted their question, and during the time I was voting to close and the popup window was open, they added *"Edit- I would prefer if it was written in php"*.

I need to note that this happened during the grace period, therefore there is no edit history; I know what I saw (originally) and didn't see and their *"Edit etc."* was not part of the original post.

The window to vote to close was opened for me before they added that, yet at that very moment that I was going to vote and they added that extra text, the close vote popup closed/disappeared by itself.

Is this a new bug or has it always reacted that way? I have never seen this happen (to me) before.

Comment: That is a new bug related to [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333831/question-editor-auto-closes-when-another-edit-is-submitted-while-editing) if you ask me.

Comment: @rene I would say so. Seems like he's not a happy camper neither; I don't blame him one bit. Thanks for the link Rene.

Comment: Looks to me like this is actually good thing. If there was an edit, you should check, if the question should still be closed and you can't really do this, if the vote-to-close popup floats above the question.

Comment: @fabian That makes sense. I didn't see it that way, thanks. *Cheers*

Comment: @rene "99 little bugs in the code, 99 little bugs in the code. Take one down, patch it around, 117 little bugs in the code"